# jQuery select only the parent li in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to make this fade effect only happen when I hover over the parent LI's but it seems to fade in and out when I hover over the items in the dropdown too?

Any ideas???

I've tried a heap of examples on here, but I can't seem to figure this out for the life of me, and it's really starting to bug me!

Thanks heaps guys!

```
<style type="text/css">

/*style the main menu*/
.myMenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.myMenu li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif #111;
}

.myMenu li a:link {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#09F;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    margin:0;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    color:#111;
}

.myMenu li a:hover {
    background-color:#0CF;  
}

/*style the sub menu*/
.myMenu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.myMenu li ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:none;
}

.myMenu li ul li a:link, .myMenu li ul li a:visited {
    background-color:#09F;
    width:auto;
}

.myMenu li ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#0CF;  
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.myMenu li').on('mouseover', openSubMenu);
        $('.myMenu li').on('mouseout', closeSubMenu);

        function openSubMenu() {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeIn()
        };

        function closeSubMenu() {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeOut();   
        };

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<ul class="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a>
       <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 5</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this selector:

```
$('.myMenu > li').on('mouseover', openSubMenu);
```

instead of:

```
$('.myMenu li').on('mouseover', openSubMenu);
```

(obviously, apply to the same selector in other places)

Although, I like to use:

```
$('.myMenu').children('li').on('mouseover', openSubMenu);
```

It only selects the children `<li>` elements from the `.myMenu` element.

Also, it's necessary that the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events be used instead, because of weird bubbling issues.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MdfHB/

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/children/
- http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/
- http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work? When I hover the LI's in the sub menu it still fades in and out?

Comment: @user2218028 Sorry, change the events to be `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. I didn't see that at first, but `mouseover` and `mouseleave` have weird effects on descendants

Comment: @user2218028 I updated my answer with this information, and added a demo with all the changes I've explained, and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/dtbaf/1/

```
  $('.myMenu > li').on('mouseenter', openSubMenu);
  $('.myMenu > li').on('mouseleave', closeSubMenu);
```

Which selects only the immediate child `li`s of `myMenu` class.
Also use [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events..

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried it already, the submenus fade in and out when you go between them.